# In wso2 esb how to store a multipart/form data request payload and use later in the sequene

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In wso2 ESB I'm having the below request payload of multipart/formdata.

```
key: file  value(file): image
key: data  value(text): {"a":"b","c":"d"}
```

But first I want to store this and later I want to use this payload. How to achive this. I mean after storing this multipart/formadata request, I am doing some other processing, then at the end I am giving response as same as the request that I've stored earlier.

I tried with property but as it stores as String it while processing afterwards multipart/formadata treats it as text(encoding as UTF-8 or text),So image will 
be treated as text.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved the above question by first setting the property using enrich mediator and then use that property afterwards using enrich mediator. Thus it preserves the format, if we store the property using the property mediator we have to store as string or OM. So , the format will not be preserved and while running it considers image encoding also as **text**.

```
<enrich>
    <source clone="false" type="body"/>
    <target type="property" property="inputpayload"/>
</enrich>
.
.
.
<enrich xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"> 
           <source clone="false" property="inputpayload"/> 
           <target action="replace" type="body"/> 
</enrich>
```